# How to display missing days of the month even is not on the database using SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures, recursive-query

I need to show a report that shows all of the days of the month. Let's say from 01 Jan 2020, to 31 Jan 2020. In order to do that, I create a stored procedure that has a start date, and a last date and I use Left Join with a table

I wrote

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATE = '2020-01-01';
DECLARE @FromDate DATE = '2020-01-31';

SELECT a1.f1, a1.f2, b.f3. b.f5
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON b.f1 = a.f1
                      AND (@FromDate IS NULL OR a.Date >= @FromDate)
                      AND (@ToDate IS NULL OR a.Date <= @ToDate)
```

The result, as no records for missing days such as 2020-01-02 is as

```
2020-01-01 f1 f2
2020-01-04 f1 f2
```

I need to display all dates, so the result will be

```
    2020-01-01 f1 f2
    2020-01-02 f1 f2
    2020-01-03 null null
    2020-01-04 f1 f2
    2020-01-05 null null
    .
    .
    2020-01-31 null null
```

I use Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, your query uses no columns from `table2` so the intend is rather unclear.  And `a1` is not defined.  And your results repeat 2020-01-02 and don't have 2020-01-03.

Comment: You need a calandar table. If you search for it, you'll find many examples how to make one, and how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive query to generate the dates, then bring the table with a `left join`.

```
with recursive all_dates as (
    select @FromDate dt
    union all 
    select dateadd(day, 1, dt) from all_dates where dt < @ToDate
)
select d.dt, t.f1, t.f2
from all_dates d
left join table1 on t.date = d.date
```

I don't see what `table2` is there for, since your query returns columns from `table1` only, so I removed if from the query.

If you  need to generate periods of more than 100 days, then you can need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the dates you want.  If you had one table, this would look like:

```
with dates as (
      select @startdate as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < @enddate
     )
select d.dte, t1.f1, t1.f2
from dates d cross join
     table1 t1;
```